# Proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \delta_{x_n}$ is a measure determined by another function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> **Definition:** Let $H(x)$ be the Heaviside function defined to be $0$ when $x<0$ and $1$ when $x \ge 0$.  Let the series of positive terms $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ be convergent and define the function $f$ by the formula $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n H(x-x_n)$, where $x_n$ is a given countable sequence of distinct real numbers.

From another post, we have that $f$ is continuous to the right, discontinuous at $x_n$ and continuous elsewhere.  We can take these propositions as facts in this post.

> **Problem:** Prove that the measure determined by the function $f$ is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \delta_{x_n}$, where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac measure at $x$, namely the one satisfying $\delta_x(A) = 1$ if and only if $x \in A$, and $0$ otherwise.

Here I'm not sure what it means for $f$ to "determine a measure".  How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Every non-decreasing right-continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ gives rise to a unique measure $\mu_f$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ called the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure. You need to show that the measure $f$ gives rise to is in fact $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\delta_{x_n}$. Hint: the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure is characterized by $\mu_f((a,b])=f(b)-f(a)$ for $a<b$.